# Calculating maximum gain of an antenna depending on a parameter

Tags: antenna, gain

Consider an antenna that radiates in a direction for which the normalized gain is:

$$G(\theta, \phi) = \cos^n(\theta),\ 0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Calculate the maximum directivity as a function of n and justify what happens when we increase the value of n.

Since gain and directivity are proportional, I assume that when G is maximized, so will be the directivity D. I have considered taking the derivative with respect to n and setting it equal to 0, but it seems like a too trivial solution to me.
​

Comment: I think you're right, it is trivial.  Without doing the math, think about where cos^n(θ) is a maximum.  And it's a maximum regardless of the value of n.